# Unknown related component on class with Doctrine inheritance, Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, database, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony 1.4 project to show `products` in a `category` product view. Products can be viewed in different categories so I have a many-to-many relationship between product and category.

I also have different types of products so have used Doctrine inheritance to define them as most of them share a lot of the same properties.

Now the problem I am having is that when trying to add a product to a category I am getting the error:

```
Unknown record property / related component "CategoriesFeaturedIn" on "MultiProduct"
```

CategoriesFeaturedIn is the property on the Product that holds which categories it is in as defined in the Doctrine schema.

MultiProduct inherits from Product so should have this property yes?

I will post below my schema and the code i'm using for adding a product to a category. Hopefully someone can help and I can provide any more information as neccessary.

--

**Schema:** (not the whole file)

```
Category:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [title]
  columns:
    id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
      notnull:          true
      autoincrement:    true
    title:
      type:             string(255)
      notnull:          true
    image:
      type:             string(255)
    store_id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
    sort_order:
      type:             integer
  relations:
    Store:
      class:            Store
      local:            store_id
      onDelete:         CASCADE
      foreignAlias:     Categories
    Parents:
      class:            Category
      refClass:         CategoryCategory
      foreign:          parent_category_id
      foreignAlias:     Subcategories

CategoryFeaturedProduct:
  columns:
    category_id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
    product_id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
  relations:
    Category:
      foreignAlias:     FeaturedProducts
      onDelete:         CASCADE
    Product:
      foreignAlias:     CategoriesFeaturedIn
      onDelete:         CASCADE

Product:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [title]
  columns:
    id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
      notnull:          true
      autoincrement:    true
    title:
      type:             string(255)
    description:
      type:             string(255)
    link:
      type:             string(255)
    image:
      type:             string(255)
    large_image:
      type:             string(255)
    featured_image:
      type:             string(255)
    sku:
      type:             string(64)
    mpid:
      type:             string(64)
    stock:
      type:             integer
    price:
      type:             decimal
    rrp:
      type:             decimal
    was_price:
      type:             decimal
    rating:
      type:             decimal
    sort_order:
      type:             integer
    promotion_id:
      type:             integer
    manufacturer_id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
  relations:
    Promotion:
      class:            Promotion
      local:            promotion_id
      onDelete:         SET NULL
      foreignAlias:     Products
    Manufacturer:
      class:            Manufacturer
      local:            manufacturer_id
      onDelete:         CASCADE
      foreignAlias:     Products
    Categories:
      class:            Category
      refClass:         ProductCategory
      foreignAlias:     Products
    CategoriesFeaturedIn:
      class:            Category
      refClass:         CategoryFeaturedProduct
      foreignAlias:     FeaturedProducts

MultiProduct:
  inheritance:
    extends:            Product
    type:               column_aggregation
    keyField:           type
    keyValue:           2
```

**Code:**

```
$product = ProductTable::getInstance()->find($prod_id);
$category = CategoryTable::getInstance()->find($cat_id);
$product->addCategoryFeaturedIn($category);
```

**Product Class:**

```
public function addCategoryFeaturedIn($category)
{
    $this->CategoriesFeaturedIn[] = $category;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to resolve this issue although I'm not entirely sure on the answer but I did two things and everything worked.

Firstly I reordered my schema file so it reads like so:

```
Category:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [title]
  columns:
    id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
      notnull:          true
      autoincrement:    true
    title:
      type:             string(255)
      notnull:          true
    image:
      type:             string(255)
    store_id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
    sort_order:
      type:             integer
  relations:
    Store:
      class:            Store
      local:            store_id
      onDelete:         CASCADE
      foreignAlias:     Categories
    Parents:
      class:            Category
      refClass:         CategoryCategory
      foreign:          parent_category_id
      foreignAlias:     Subcategories

Product:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [title]
  columns:
    id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
      notnull:          true
      autoincrement:    true
    title:
      type:             string(255)
    description:
      type:             string(255)
    link:
      type:             string(255)
    image:
      type:             string(255)
    large_image:
      type:             string(255)
    featured_image:
      type:             string(255)
    sku:
      type:             string(64)
    mpid:
      type:             string(64)
    stock:
      type:             integer
    price:
      type:             decimal
    rrp:
      type:             decimal
    was_price:
      type:             decimal
    rating:
      type:             decimal
    sort_order:
      type:             integer
    promotion_id:
      type:             integer
    manufacturer_id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
  relations:
    Promotion:
      class:            Promotion
      local:            promotion_id
      onDelete:         SET NULL
      foreignAlias:     Products
    Manufacturer:
      class:            Manufacturer
      local:            manufacturer_id
      onDelete:         CASCADE
      foreignAlias:     Products
    Categories:
      class:            Category
      refClass:         ProductCategory
      foreignAlias:     Products
    CategoriesFeaturedIn:
      class:            Category
      refClass:         CategoryFeaturedProduct
      foreignAlias:     FeaturedProducts

MultiProduct:
  inheritance:
    extends:            Product
    type:               column_aggregation
    keyField:           type
    keyValue:           2

CategoryFeaturedProduct:
  columns:
    category_id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
    product_id:
      type:             integer
      primary:          true
  relations:
    Category:
      foreignAlias:     FeaturedProducts
      onDelete:         CASCADE
    Product:
      foreignAlias:     CategoriesFeaturedIn
      onDelete:         CASCADE
```

I also changed my Product method to read as so:

```
public function addCategory($category)
{
    $this->getCategories()->add($category);
}
```

I imagine the reordering of the schema file is what actually did the trick and fixed this problem which does suggest that you need to define relationships in the schema **after** you have defined the actual tables which are related.

The change of the method probably didnt affect this but its worth noting as this is what I believe to be a better way to add to a many-to-many relationship.